# Call PowerShell script from Outlook rule on public mailbox

Tags: vba, powershell, outlook

I want to be able to specify a rule which calls an API which takes JSON. To call this API I have a PowerShell script that takes a `-Message` parameter. To do this I [found](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_28057708.html) the following Visual Basic script:

```
Process.Start("powershell", "-noexit -file 'c:\<path>\file.ps1' -ArgumentList VARIABLE")"
```

Now I want this rule to be implemented in Outlook and also working while my machine is off (so there is no access to C:/ I guess). Is this possible? And if so, Am I on the right track?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you create some kind of Exchange server-side rule, you won't be able to run that type of rule while the computer is turned off. Outlook will need to be up and running to process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want this rule to be implemented in Outlook and also working while my machine is off (so there is no access to C:/ I guess). Is this possible? And if so, Am I on the right track?

Outlook rules is a client's feature. So, it can be run in Outlook only. You need to keep Outlook running to get the solution working correctly. You can create a rule in Outlook and then assign a VBA macro sub where you can call the required powershell script. The VBA sub should be in the following format:

```
public sub test(mail as MailItem)
   '
end sub
```

where the mail object is an Outlook item to which the rule is applied.